# About the pattern to overcome the one update per second/entity limit on google datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I read this [document](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/fast-and-reliable-ranking-in-datastore/) and among several very relevant topics, some of them are key to a scalability problem I am facing.

Basically the document states that it is possible to overcome the 1 per second update ratio per entity that basically me drove me to `redis` in a use case that would not demand me to do it.

"a *(google)* software engineer in the Datastore team had mentioned a technique to obtain much higher throughput than one update per second on an entity group"

"The basic idea of `Job Aggregation` is to use a `single thread` to process a batch of updates. Because there is only one thread and only one transaction open on the entity group, there are no transaction failures due to concurrent updates. You can find similar ideas in other storage products such as `VoltDb` and `Redis`."

This is very useful to me but I don't have any clue on how this works.

Just creating a service and serialising (pull queue) upserts to a specific Kind could solve the issue? How datastore could be sure that no other thread would suddenly begin to upsert?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is important to keep in mind that Job Aggregation is not part of Datastore. As the documentation says, you need to use a single batch of updates. You can take a look here [Batch operations](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#batch_operations) to know how to upsert multiple entities.

About your second question, Datastore is not the responsible to ensure that other thread begin to upsert, you must to ensure that this not happens to get a better performance.

Here [Datastore best practices](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#entities) there are other best practices that Google recommends to get better performance.

Comment: I am familiar with batch operations but if I try to upsert two elements with the same key in the batch upsert operation it will failure (in one thread). The link I sent states that it is possible to overcome this limit and so I could even use Datastore as a ranking system

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you're trying to run? I'm curious because, in the first link there is an example of upserting two elements with the same key. So maybe we can find something within your code.